# Issues with WebView2 in WPF Usercontrol Embeded in Word VSTO CustomTaskPane

Tags: c#, vsto, wpf-controls, webview2

I switched from `WebBrowser` control to `WebView2` in my VSTO project, and I so much love the seamless rendering of pages using the updated control. However, I am having an issue with the automatic disposal of CustomTaskPaneCollections that happens when the application is closed.

The problem is that I get an exception whenever I close the Word application, mainly if the CustomTaskPane that has `WebView2` embedded in it is open at least once during the last Word application process. It is a COMException, as shown in the image below:

[image]

It seems after the automatic CustomTaskPaneCollections `Dispose()` method, which is usually called whenever the Word application is closed and which causes all embedded child controls to be disposed of, the system still tries to access the `WebView2` control, which keeps causing this exception to be raised.

How do I handle this issue, please? I've tried everything I could do. I am using WPF UserControl for embedding the `WebView2` instead of Winfrom UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is caused by you not properly releasing a COM reference, this dirty patch that could work:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: Okay. Let me try this right away.

Comment: This didn't help!

Comment: Well, then the reason is something else. In your place, I would try to debug your add-in in Visual Studio (set a breakpoint on unhandled exceptions, and see from where that one is thrown).

Comment: It was actually a bug in the `WebView2` library. I was using version 1.0.2210.55 (released since Decemeber 11, 2023). After upgrading to the latest version 1.0.2420.47 of the nuget package (released yesterday), the problem (exception) has disappeared. Thanks.